# Dynamic Quiz App Answer Validation issue in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I have a database with this structure And i have 4 question there. My job is display 2 random question and their options and when user hit submit it should check the `correct_ans` and display a result.

```
Qid | Question | A | B | C | D | Correct_ans
1   | Question |   |   |   |   |Correct Ans
2   | Question |   |   |   |   |Correct Ans
3   | Question |   |   |   |   |Correct Ans
4   | Question |   |   |   |   |Correct Ans
```

## Here is my code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['test'])){
$x = $_POST["$id"];
echo $x;
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
include("db-con.php");
$sql1 = "SELECT * from questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1,$con);

    echo"<form method='post' action=''>";
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
         $id = 'q' . $row1['quesid'];
         $question = $row1['question'];
         $solution = $row1['solution'];
         $ans_array = array($row1['A'],$row1['X'],$row1['Y'],$row1['Z']);
         $test = shuffle($ans_array);
    // Generate Questions and Display Options   

        echo $question . '<br />';
        echo "<input type='radio' value='$ans_array[0]' name=\"$id\" />" . $ans_array[0]. '<br />';
        echo "<input type='radio' value='$ans_array[1]' name=\"$id\" />" . $ans_array[1] .  '<br />';
        echo "<input type='radio' value='$ans_array[2]' name=\"$id\" />" . $ans_array[2] .  '<br />';
        echo "<input type='radio' value='$ans_array[3]' name=\"$id\" />" . $ans_array[3] .  '<br />';

     }
    echo"<input type='submit' name='test' Value='Submit' />";
    echo"</form>";


?>


</body>
</html>
```

## My Problem is

When i hit submit i am not able to get the question id and not able to check from database. When i tried to access the `$id` to check the selected answer i am always getting index error.

If i understand correctly `$id` is not a global variable that's why i am not getting it after i submit the form. I tried to put `$id` as global but again the same error .

Can anyone help me to find this solution.

Thanks & Regards
Lorry

Comment: You provided the code that does work and not the code that doesn't work, which is the code that you are having a problem with, which is the code you need us to help you fix? Nothing strange in that for you? See a slight problem maybe?

Comment: i Want to how to catch the values after i hit submit and how to check for the result. I am not sure about what way i should go

Comment: Well, the `name` attribute you give to each of your `input` fields will show up in `$_POST`. You're putting `$id` there, which not likely what you meant to do. Instead put `$id` an hidden input (like `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id">` instead and name your answer inputs something `name="answer"` then you get grab the values from `$_POST['answer']` and `$_POST['id']`, respectively.

Comment: can you tell me the code ? I didnt get you . But i am searching for hidden thing may be i will get some idea. Thanks anyway to guide me . Cheers

Comment: I just did. Did you read?

Answer (score 1):

Below code is to generate random question. This will select random question.

```
function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity) 
{    
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}

$a = (randomGen(1,4,3)); //generates 2 unique random numbers


for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
  $q = $a[$i];    
}
```

and for retrieving id you have to add hidden field

```html
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="value of id whicch is generated by random number">
```